# Правильно ли расставлены запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

"Ребята, познакомьтесь, это Миша, и он будет учиться с вами".

Answer (score 1):

Все верно. Я бы тоже так расставила.

Answer (score 0):

Ребята, познакомьтесь: это Миша, и он будет учиться с вами

Comment: Товарищ, какими правилами руководствовались при постановке двоеточия?